# Criar arquivo template XML no Intellij Idea Jetbrain

Tags: xml

Tenho dificuldades de colocar na relação NEW da Ide Intellij da JetBrain. Ou seja, quando criou um projeto Java, clico com o botao direito no projeto e vou em New não vejo a opção de criar um arquivo XML, porem quando vou em Edit Templates ele esta lá, como faço pra colocar na lista de arquivos(extenções) disponíveis em New?

Comment: Coloquei a resposta, mas é estranho, na minha versao veio como defaulto, nem posso edita-lo. Que versão vc esta usando?

Answer (score 0):

Vá em: `File | Settings | Editor | File Types`, clique no sinal de mais `+` para adicionar um novo tipo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]